# Transform object into keymap structure?

Tags: python

I'm looking for a quick way to transform an object into a structure like this in Python:

```
obj = [{"id": "a"}, {"id": "b"}, {"id": "c"}]
```

Into:

```
mapobj = {"a": {"id": "a"}, "b": {"id": "b"}, "c": {"id": "c"}}
```

In javascript we can use losdash's `_.mapkeys()`for this.

Comment: Since you mentioned JS... in vanilla JS this could be solved by e.g. `const mapObj = obj.reduce((acc, dct) => { acc[dct["id"]] = dct; return acc; }, {});`

Comment: ...or with using the comma operator: `const mapObj = obj.reduce((acc, dct) => (acc[dct["id"]] = dct, acc), {});`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mapobj = {dct["id"]: dct for dct in obj}
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
mapObj = dict(map(lambda dct: (dct["id"], dct), obj))
```

[Here](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/FY7zUYd) is an online test.